# Geodataframe not plotting properly in geopandas

Tags: python, geopandas

I am playing around with the `gdf.plot` method which is supposed to facilitate plotting geodataframes using `geopandas`. The reason is that I would like to avoid jumping from QGIS to python while developing scripts and just focus on the programming.

Unfortunately for a simple polygon (granted it has a hole inside) this method seems to have problems. On QGIS I get the following plot:

[image]

On matplotlib I get the following plot:

[image]

I am quite sure that the QGIS version is correct.  The geojson file for which this all applies contains the following:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ 1.0, 2.0 ], [ 1.0, 1.5 ], [ 0.5, 1.5 ], [ 0.0, 1.5 ], [ 0.0, 0.0 ], [ 1.0, 0.0 ], [ 1.0, 0.5 ], [ 1.5, 0.5 ], [ 2.0, 0.5 ], [ 2.0, 2.0 ], [ 1.0, 2.0 ] ], [ [ 1.0, 1.5 ], [ 1.0, 1.0 ], [ 1.5, 1.0 ], [ 1.5, 1.5 ], [ 1.0, 1.5 ] ] ] } }
]
}
```

Why does `geopandas` not recognize that there must be a hole in there?

Comment: It's not a matter of geopandas, but a matter of matplotlib. Geopandas' plot is built on top of matplotlib's plot, so you have to use similar arguments. Here you can check how to plot complex polygons in matplotlib like your case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8919719/how-to-plot-a-complex-polygon

Comment: Technically shouldn't this be handled by `geopandas`? What is the added value if I have to plot the polygons from scratch in this case?

Comment: You open the GeoPandas issue 951   [Plotting polygon with hole goes wrong in case of identical exterior/interior coordinates ordef](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/951) with the same example and answers

Comment: Yes I did. If you want we can delete this quesion, but an answer here would also give some exposure in SE